# Can't use scrollbars of dropdowns (HTML select) in Chrome 32

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

After an update of Google Chrome to version 32 (the current stable version), the scroll bar on  dropdowns (HTML  elements) cannot be scrolled with dragging. It can only be scrolled by the mouse wheel.

Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Update:** The bug has been fixed in [version 32.0.1700.102](http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.ro/2014/01/stable-channel-update_27.html), released on 2014-01-27.

---

This is a known bug in Chrome 32.0.1700.76 m on Windows 7, and the [devs are aware of](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=334522), but until they fix it, there is a quick (4 clicks) fix:

1. Right click the Chrome icon on your Windows Desktop
2. Click Properties
3. Select the Compatibility Tab
4. Check "Disable Visual Themes" 
   (Click OK to acknowledge)

You're done. The next time you start Chrome from the Desktop, the scroll will function just as before.

If you have Chrome pinned to the task bar or Start menu, then instead of 1. and 2. , you'll have to:

1. a) Right click on the pinned Chrome icon
   b)Then again right click on "Google Chrome" (just on top of the option "Unpin this program from ...")
2. Click Properties.

I've made a video showing the steps on [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dUKGRaVIxm4).

Comment: This was successfully fixed and released as of 32.0.1700.102 m.

Comment: To everyone that sees this (top google result for the issue now), even though it's in the latest release, you'll need to force this update to get it *now*. Menu -> About Google Chrome -> Update

Answer (score 0):

It's being fixed. The fix is live now in the test versions of Chrome so it should come to stable shortly.

It's verified that this is working with Chrome's version 32.0.1700.102 m.